# spatstat deleting marks from a point pattern and subseuently the points

Tags: r, data-manipulation, spatstat

I am looking at the point pattern data set in spatstat anemones which has 231 points with marks attached to them which define the diameter.. I want to delete the marks and the points within the point pattern when the diameter is equal to 2

Here is the data:
>

> [1] 6 4 4 6 3 3 5 3 5 4 4 6 5 3 4 7 4 6 6 5 4 4 5 3 3 6 4 5 4 4 5 3 3 5
>   3 4 5 8 5 4 6 5 6 4 5 3 3 4 5 6 4 4 3 4 4 6 5 4 3 6 5 3  [63] 3 6 5 3
>   3 2 5 7 4 4 4 3 3 4 3 6 2 6 6 3 4 3 7 6 3 4 2 7 4 5 4 4 4 6 4 3 3 3 3
>   6 7 3 7 3 2 4 3 5 2 3 4 4 3 3 3 6 3 4 5 3 6 3 [125] 7 5 3 3 4 4 5 4 4
>   6 5 3 3 3 5 3 6 5 5 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 4 7 4 6 5 7 6 3 6 5 4 6 4 5 4 5 3
>   6 3 3 6 4 6 4 4 6 3 5 3 4 6 5 5 4 5 [187] 4 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 4 5 5 5 4 6
>   4 4 5 3 5 4 3 4 4 4 3 4 5 5 3 3 5 3 4 5 6 2 5 2 3 2 3 3 7 5 4

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to use the generic R command `subset`:

```
X <- subset(anemones, marks != 2)
```

From the question it is not quite clear whether you want to get rid of all the marks after deleting these points. In that case use `unmark`:

```
X <- unmark(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm reading this as meaning you wish to remove observations when `anemones$marks` is equal to 2.

If so this should do it:

```
updated_anemones <- anemones[!anemones$marks == 2,]
```

Comment: It is recommended to use the accessor function `marks()` rather than manually extracting the marks from the `ppp` object, and also there is no need for the trailing comma as `anemones` is a `ppp` and not a `data.frame`, so in my opinion it would be better to use: `X <- anemones[marks(anemones) != 2]`